# Is the "not null" constraint redundant if used with foreign key constraint?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Take this example of a column definition:

```
permission_id int not null references ugp_permissions (id)
```

Is the `not null` constraint redundant in this example? I think it is, since the provided value has to match on the referenced table. However, when there are null records on the referenced column, would that classify as a match for the foreign key?

Comment: Why not try and see. A great exercise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s not redundant in this situation because such a constraint prevents omission of a `permission_id`. Sometimes you want a foreign keyed column to be nullable because it is not required (just as not every **citizen** in a citizens table went to a university, so a `university_id` column can be null). In other cases, the column should not be null, just as every **student** lshould be associated with a `university_id`.

In this situation, the `permission_id` is required because it is a `not null` column

Disclosure: I work for [EnterpriseDB (EDB)](http://enterprisedb.com)

Answer (score 0):

When you omit "not null" the value can be null, but when it is not null it's checked against the referenced table.

Answer (score 0):

No, if there are null records on the referenced column, they will not match for the foreign key.